# function works with onclick but not working via javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Why does the function `changeText` work when called by `onclick="changeText('tare.e')"` but not when called within the JavaScript

```
function changeText(idname,newtext)
{

   document.getElementById(idname).value = newtext;
}

changeText('tare.e','from javascript' );
// Calling here causes the error: `Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined` 

</script>

<input id="tare.e" value="text" >
<input id="tare.e_button" type="button"  value="BUTTON"  onclick="   changeText('tare.e','from button')"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript runs before the HTML is loaded completely.

Put the following around your JavaScript code...

```
window.onload = function () {

   changeText('tare.e','from javascript' );

};
```

This ensures your code runs when the page loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling changeText() before the document has loaded. If you want to execute the function when the document first loads call it in the onload event, e.g.:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText(idname,newtext) {
       document.getElementById(idname).value = newtext;
    }

    function window_onload()
    {
    changeText('tare.e','from javascript' );
    }
    </script>
    </head>
<body onload='window_onload()'>
<input id="tare.e" value="text" >
<input id="tare.e_button" type="button"  value="BUTTON"  onclick="   changeText('tare.e','from button')"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps , but I am trying to change the text in the input box without using any event. For instance after generating new text with a function, put it in the box without any other event. What I need is an event like "whenfinishedcalculating"

Answer (score 0):

i found [this](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) about functions .. am still confused about functions too , hope it can help you